# SPRING jdbcTemplate.update java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'have already solved the problem but i just wondered why jdbcTemplate not accept my query with the jdbcTemplate.update but work with jdbcTemplate.execute, here the code for the example with coordinates:

```
String query = "UPDATE geodomaindocument SET latitude=? , longitude=?  WHERE url=?";
Object[] values = new Object[]{0,0,"http://example.com"}
jdbcTemplate.update(query, values);
```

return this exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE geodomaindocument SET latitude=? , longitude=?  WHERE url=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
```

but is worked with the same query but with the execute:

```
 query = "UPDATE geodomaindocument SET latitude='"+values[0]+"', longitude='"+values[1]+"' WHERE url='http://example.com'";
jdbcTemplate.execute(query);
```

Ty in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**
Ok,I'm just stupid, it's was a simple index error.

Comment: I am having the same issue right here, can you explain how you fix this in detail? Thank you so much~

Comment: It's been a while , if i remember correctly the problem was the array index values[i] was null or empty

Answer (score 0):

Your latitude and longitude are of type string. Try this

```
Object[] values = new Object[]{"0","0","http://example.com"}
```

Comment: No, that's not the problem, otherwise spring would use a String [] and not an Object [] to insert the values of the variables.